# Why Laravel can't find controller using "/"?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing issues on laravel - I have route in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth/LoginController@logout')
```

and when I'm trying to use it I'm receiving alert:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Auth/LoginController] does not exist.

changing route to `Auth\LoginController@logout` resolves the issue - but I think this is wrong solution.
and yes- I'm running it on windows so in theory \ is correct but previously in other projects laravel didn't had this issue

Comment: _"but I think this is wrong solution"_ - No, using backslash is the correct solution. In PHP, you separate namespaces using backslash, not forward slash (regardless of OS). It's file paths that can be different depending on OS, not namespace separators.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson its not about folder paths, its namespaces that php uses \ for its names.

Comment: @YahYa - Please read my comment again. I never said the OP asked about paths, but I mentioned it since they wrote: _"I'm running it on windows so in theory \ is correct"_. They seem to confuse paths and namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct solution, that's how PHP is declare it's namespaces

Comment: Ok, so why when i'm using vagrant - Route::get('/logout', 'Auth/LoginController@logout') version is accepted without issue?

Comment: @DarekKaczyński - Namespaces uses backslashes, not forward slashes. That's just how PHP works (and have worked since the introduction of namespaces). If it has worked for you to use forward slashes when passing namespaces as a string (like in the route), then there must have been some code somewhere converting them for you. We can't answer that, but we can, and now have, answered how PHP works.

Comment: ok, thx for your time ;)